# Weird compiler errors in Travis CI that don't happen on local machine

Tags: c++, linux, dependencies, travis-ci

I have made a [GitHub test repo](https://github.com/kim366/Travis-CI-Test) for playing around with Travis CI and it worked fine, until I tried using external dependencies. In the `.travis.yml` I have

```
install:
  - sudo apt-get install libsfml-dev
```

and this command successfully gets executed on the Travis machine, but on the compile, I get errors like

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:6:5: error: ‘CircleShape’ is not a member of ‘sf’
main.cpp:6:21: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘shape’
main.cpp:7:5: error: ‘shape’ was not declared in this scope
```

on `g++` and

```
main.cpp:6:9: error: no member named 'CircleShape' in namespace 'sf'
    sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
    ~~~~^
main.cpp:7:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'shape'
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);
    ^
```

on `clang++`.

Neither on my Windows Machine nor on my Linux VM I get these errors and the code is the example code from the SFML tutorials.

There doesn't seem anything wrong with the `install` command, since the compilers don't say anything about an incorrect header.

What causes such errors? How could I fix them? Did I do something wrong with the `install` command?

Comment: From what I recollect, Travis uses Ubuntu 12.04, which is very old. Maybe there's an issue with the version of SFML it installed?

Comment: Ah, interesting hint; I'll look into it

Comment: @GoodDeeds Awesome, it works! Didn't think it would be as easy

Comment: Good. Btw, how is the title connected to the rest of the question? Maybe it could be edited to make this easier to find?

Comment: @GoodDeeds The thing is that I didn't know what the cause was and I don't really know a more fitting title. If someone knows one, please edit it

Comment: Also, from what I've learnt on SO, you don't put your tags in the title, so that's the most descriptive I could come up with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @GoodDeeds posted in the comments, the Ubuntu distribution is outdated.

Add `dist: trusty` (as pointed out by @joepd) into your `.travis.yml` file to use the up-to-date distribution.

Comment: You probably want to make that `dist: trusty`.

Comment: Is it? Okay, I just quickly looked at Ubuntu's download page and kylin was what I saw.

Comment: Have a look at the Travis documentation.